# Mock a member of class but not the class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
public class person
{
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public Car PersonCar { get; set; }
}
```

and the Car class is something like:

```
public class Car
{
    public bool CanStart { get; set; }
}
```

Now in my test I'm using the Person class but I would need the Car member of the Person class to be mocked and always return true if CanStart is called. Is that possible ?

Comment: Why do you want to mock this? Why not just use a real `Car` object? My guess is that your real situation has relevant aspects that you haven't explained to us.

Comment: Why don't you just create a mock of `Car` whose `CanStart` always returns true, and then set your `person`s (capitalization?) `PersonCar` (naming?) property to that mock?

Comment: Or, you can create own class `CarTest` that derives from `Car` and override `CanStart` property. Then you can: `person.PersonCar = new CarTest()`. `CanStart` property need to be virtual of course.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
var person = new Person();
var mockCar = new Mock<Car>();
mockCar.SetupGet(c => c.CanStart).Returns(true);

person.Car = mockCar.Object;
```

Comment: The property would have to be declared as virtual.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Or create interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you want CanStart to always return true, why mock it? You can just do this:

```
var person = new Person
{
    PersonCar = new Car
    {
        CanStart = true
    }
};
```